# Sketchup Ruby InputPoint.face method on Image object?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have one problem with InputPoint.face method in Sketchup Ruby API.

When i import one image object and then  draw 5-edges polygon on this image. I used InputPoint.face for getting number of edges in the polygon after clicking on it. I think the output is 5, but actually, the output is 4

If i remove the image , result will be 5.

I don't understand why the output is like that, and what can i do to get output 5?

This is my code

```
# The onLButtonDOwn method is called when the user presses the left mouse button.
def onLButtonDown(flags, x, y, view)
    @ip = view.inputpoint x,y
    @f = @ip.face
    aEdges  = @f.edges
    puts aEdges.length
end
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have drawn pentagon faces on the `Image` entity you imported? And when you use `InputPoint` to click on one of the pentagons you get a face with four edges?

What happens here is probably that you are getting the `Face` inside the `Image` entity. Under the hood an `Image` entity is a special component instance. You can in fact find the definition for the `Image` entity in `model.definitions`.
For more details on SketchUp and Components, Groups and Images read this article: http://www.thomthom.net/thoughts/2012/02/definitions-and-instances-in-sketchup/

`InputPoint` and `PickHelper` seem to let you pick the face inside the `Image` entity instead of stopping when it hits the `Image` entity.
You will probably want to filter out your results before using them and you probably wantto use the `PickHelper` class instead of `InputPoint`.
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/pickhelper.php
http://www.thomthom.net/thoughts/2013/01/pickhelper-a-visual-guide/

`InputPoint` is more for getting 3d points for inference, while `PickHelper` is best to use to pick and select entities.

You can check the `Face` entity you get from `InputPoint` and it's parent to verify which face it is and what context it belongs to.